# How to make RegExp with specific inputs in flutter

Tags: flutter

Flutter

i want `RegExp` for only allowing the following inputs :

1- numbers (0-9) English.

2- underscore _.

3- hash #.

4- one space " " (not more than one)

5- any language on planet that people use for their life .

and refuse any inputs not mentioned in previous points

now i am using the following

```
RegExp(????).hasMatch(value);
```

thanks

Comment: Short of having to consider every character type in every language that might need to be terminated or validated out, you could use something like this :
RegExp(r'^[0-9A-Za-z_# ]+$').hasMatch(value);   WHERE value is the value you testing against of course.  Will type up a full answer if this works for you.

Comment: thanks , i already test your RegExp but it does not match my mentioned points . yes please if you have RegExp matching my mentioned points please write the answer

Comment: Oh did I miss one? What criteria is not matching?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually ruling out.  "any language" means you pretty much need nearly all of unicode, right?

Comment: Your provided RegExp work as expected for all my points except the language part . Yes i want accept any language like English Arabic Turkish and more more languages as mush as possible (The letters that people use in their languages and understand)

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, you would have to declare the problem characters from other languages that are conflicting with your application, then either filter them out, or terminate them if that is the issue.  We can update the regex as you find characters that do not work with your application design.

Comment: Ok Can you update it to allow for any language letter as mush as possible ? The most widely spoken languages in the world

Comment: i only want to show dialog to users if there an input that not mentioned in my allowed points

Comment: allows any kind of letter from any language

Comment: I mean if you are testing and getting fails .. add the offending character to the regex and work your data until all the problem characters are either allowed or filtered as needed.

Comment: Ahh okay i understand now , but it hard for me to test each single letter from any language . is there better way to make auto accept any kind of letter from any language ?

Comment: you can do a reverse check; you can check for the symbols you don't want. if they are present you can pull up an error. If you could provide specifics of what you don't want, answering would be easier

Comment: good idea but i know what does i need exactly .  but don't know what does i don't want . i mean there are a huge number of symbols that i don't want . i hope it easy to understand me

Comment: instead of saying i don't want private symbols it easy to me to say i want only as mush as possible of any letter of any spoken language

Comment: in this way i can make sure there no unwanted input has been accepted

Comment: do you think is that mush of hard that there no a shortcut RegExp that allow for any letter of any language ?

Comment: you can try this regex if this helps you I can create an answer fro this RegExp(r'[^~`!@\$%\^&\*\(\)\{\}\[\]\-=\+\/\?\<>"]*'); if the string matches this then the input is invalid. You can remove any character that you would like to include in the input. This is a kind of reverse check.